# Linking to files online

Tags: symlink, ln

Is is possible to soft-link to a file on a web server? For example, if I have files hosted on localhost, is there a way to make `ln -s http://localhost/file.txt ~/myremotefile.txt` work as possible? I tried linking to a file or two from the internet with `ln -s`, but when I try to access the file, I get a "No such file or directory" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be done via FUSE, e.g.

- http://httpfs.sourceforge.net/
- https://github.com/cyrus-and/httpfs
- https://github.com/danielrozenberg/httpfs
- https://pypi.org/project/simple-httpfs/

And others. Normal Linux utilities e.g. `cp` have no idea and no logic to work with with http(s) files.

Comment: This seems to be about what I need. Thanks!